# How to disable option in select based on a table column, using Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, drop-down-menu, doctrine

I have this function that builds a select (html tag) with many options, one option for each user in the database.

I'm using PHP 7.0.33 and Symfony 3. I have tried to get two columns on the createQueryBuilder adding a ->select but it doesn't work, since it expects and objects but I return a string. I could try to make a new select for each user but I can't figure out how and I don't think it's the best way for doing it since I've already did one select before.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder

        ->add('user', EntityType::class, [

            'class' => User::class,

            'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {

                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')

                                    ->where('u.distributionList = ?1')

                                    ->setParameter(1, User::USER_TYPE);

            },

            'placeholder' => 'Select a user',

            'required' => true,

            'choice_attr' => function() {

                $disabled = true; // test only

                return $disabled ? ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : [];

            }

        ])


    ;

}
```

How can I disable the option for inactive users? Knowing that the same table that has the users has another column called enabled with values 't' (true) or 'f' for (false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Symfony documentation, you can add parameters to your callback ($choice, $key, $value) that will fulfill your needs !

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-attr

Comment: I made it work! (of pure luck), I realized I just had to do this: return['disabled' => !$choice->getEnabled()... I also had to create the function getEnabled on the User Entity. I figured out because I did a var_dump on $choice and it had lot of information like the enabled column that I needed! Thanks!